# Trader vs Torturer, where does the Silver go?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

My opponent plays a Torturer. I have a Trader in hand. I choose to gain a Curse and then reveal the Trader and gain a Silver instead. Does the Silver go to my hand like the Curse would have?
[image: Torturer]
[image: Trader]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Silver Gained from Trader works exactly the same as any other Gain; as Trader's text doesn't specify anything to the contrary, the Gained card goes directly to your discard pile.  This situation is explicitly mentioned on page 11 of [the Hinterlands instructions](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_396_gameRules.pdf):

> If the card you were going to gain was not going to your discard pile, **the Silver still goes to your discard pile**; if the card you were going to gain did not come from the Supply, the Silver still comes from the Supply.